# GoDaddy Apache 2.4 - 301 htacces Redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I had a perfectly working site before they update the servers, now I can't get redirects working?

That's what I had before:

```
RewriteEngine On
rewritecond %{http_host} ^site.com [nc]<br/>
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.site.com/$1 [r=301,nc]<br/>
redirect 301 "contact.html" http://site.com/contact.php<br/>
```

Please help!

Comment: Yes I did, no help, except a link to a Apache 2.4 documentation

Comment: do they have htaccess enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have HTML tags in the example you're showing. Also you're surrounding things with non-necessary quotes. This now uses `mod_rewrite` exclusively.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^contact.html http://www.site.com/contact.php [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.site.com/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Remember that since GoDaddy is the host, they will have directives in their `httpd.conf` file that are processed as well as any configurations you add in the `.htaccess` file.

If for some reason this doesn't work, additionally [Godaddy has their own support forums](http://support.godaddy.com/help/category/330/web-hosting-languages-and-scripts-linuxbased-languages-and-scripts-htaccess) for dealing with issues in configuration of their services.